# Add data and image as a single node and retrieve it using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, textview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using the below code to send data and images from an application but the data and image are going separately. My question is I want to send a type of user form with information and the uploaded picture.

Below is the code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




tvname= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvname);
tvnumber= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvnumber);
tvage= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvage);
tvdata= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdata);

etname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
etnumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etnumber);
etage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etage);

btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectimage);

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

btnimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
    }


});


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            String name = etname.getText().toString();
            String number = etnumber.getText().toString();
            String age = etage.getText().toString();

            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(name);
            user.setNumber(number);
            user.setAge(age);
            name = name.trim();
            number = number.trim();
            age = age.trim();
//              User user = new User(user, number, age);
            mDatabase.child("users").child(name).setValue(user);



            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())    {
                        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        String string = "Name: " +user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " +user.getNumber() + "\n Age" +user.getAge();
                        tvdata.setText(string);
                    }
                }





                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }

            });

        }
    });



}


     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
             mProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading");
             mProgressDialog.show();
             Uri uri = data.getData();

             StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
             filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                 }
             });

         }

     }
}
```

Once I send the data below is the code to retrieve the data -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
    // Not in crash process.  Do your Remote Config init here.
    System.out.println("ss");
}

tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);



btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                  //  String string = "Name: " + user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " + user.getNumber() + "\n Age: " + user.getAge();
                    String string = tv.getText() + "\nName: " + user.getUsername() + "\n Number : " + user.getNumber() + "\n Age: " + user.getAge() +"\n";

                    tv.setText(string);

                }
            }
```

Below are my queries -

1. How to send the data and image and store it in same node on firebase
2. While retrieving the data I want that different node data should be displayed in different textviews along with their corresponding image received from firebase

Below is the screenshot to make thing more clear

[Send Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf3Qv.png)

[Retrieve Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmVBe.png)

Thanks in advance for your help